# Stopping core animation on layer when some condition is met

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, core-animation

I'm trying to make 2 core animations that start at the same time and use the same curve but one of them need to be stopped if the condition is met. E.g. I have the following view on the left and want to transition to the right one.

[image]

The red views can be treated as overlays on top of yellow views even though in the beginning they are not intersecting. Imagine clicking 'item 3'. What I need to do is to animate movement of all rows to the top with distance  `-item3.frame.origin.y` but once `title3` reaches top of the screen it should stay there so the remaining `item1` `item2` will look like they are sliding behind `title3`

I tried to animate all elements using core animation with option: `UIViewAnimationsOptionLayoutSubviews` and then in `layoutSubview` stop the animation with the following code:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews {
    CALayer* presentationLayer = (CALayer*)[self.title3.layer presentationLayer];
    if (presentationLayer.frame.origin.y <= 0) {
        [self.title3.layer removeAllAnimations];
    }
}
```

but without any success. Is there any way to make it work using core animation and without mocking with `CADisplayLink`. I can't use two seperate animations because the duration for title3 animations is hard to calculate which creates a gap between `title3` and `title2` if the animation curve is not linear.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement pause/start layer animation feature according Apple's technical note [QA1673](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1673/_index.html) by following code:

```
-(void)pauseLayer:(CALayer*)layer
{
    CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];
    layer.speed = 0.0;
    layer.timeOffset = pausedTime;
}

-(void)resumeLayer:(CALayer*)layer
{
    CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer timeOffset];
    layer.speed = 1.0;
    layer.timeOffset = 0.0;
    layer.beginTime = 0.0;
    CFTimeInterval timeSincePause = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil] - pausedTime;
    layer.beginTime = timeSincePause;
}
```

Comment: I should elaborate that I had mostly problem with detecting if my view origin.y is at top while animating. Even though I'm checking presentationLayer it looks like on the first frame origin.y property is set to final value that should be set after animation is finished.